# How to run timer for each 15 seconds and to cancel it and restart it again

Tags: java, android, multithreading, timer

I have a condition in my app and that is how to control the timer. what I want is after exactly 15 seconds it go and launch the function and mean while it should get cancel and as the function got end it start itself over again from the zero.

What I have done so far is using timer , and giving it 1500 delay and 15 repetition  but it is launching the function again and again , I think I am doing it wrong in this line :

```
timer.schedule(doAsynchronousTask, 1500,1 );
```

here is my complete code of timer

```
    private final Handler handler = new Handler();
private final Timer timer = new Timer();
private final TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {

    public void run() {
        handler.post(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                launchFunction();
            }
        });

    }
};
timer.schedule(doAsynchronousTask, 1500,1 );


void launchFunction(){

     Log.d("timer","running");
     timer.cancel();
}
```

but it is not working as expected , please help me out.

Comment: try `timer.schedule(doAsynchronousTask, 1500,1500 );`

Comment: The third parameter denotes the period for the next execution. That means every millisecond after the first delay the method is getting invoked.

Comment: it is not helping me , it is launching the function every one sec

Comment: The parameters are milliseconds. I.e. 1000 ms <=> 1 sec. So you have to write 15000 for 15 seconds.

Comment: Change 1500 to 15000. The value is in milliseconds.

Comment: can you please help me in understanding what is in delays and how it works I read the official documentation but unable to get the general meaning

Comment: First parameter is the asynchronous taks you want to start. The second parameter is the initial delay before the first execution of the task. The third one - as described above - is the period between two executions. Depicted: delay -> task <- period -> task <- period -> task ...

Comment: so what should I do , if I want to run exactly after 15 seconds

Comment: i think I need to do timer.schedule(doAsynchronousTask, 0,1500 );

Answer (score 0):

read the documentation

```
/**
     * Schedule a task for repeated fixed-delay execution after a specific delay.
     *
     * @param task
     *            the task to schedule.
     * @param delay
     *            amount of time in milliseconds before first execution.
     * @param period
     *            amount of time in milliseconds between subsequent executions.
     * @throws IllegalArgumentException
     *                if {@code delay < 0} or {@code period <= 0}.
     * @throws IllegalStateException
     *                if the {@code Timer} has been canceled, or if the task has been
     *                scheduled or canceled.
     */
    public void schedule(TimerTask task, long delay, long period) {
        if (delay < 0 || period <= 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
        scheduleImpl(task, delay, period, false);
    }
```

set your schedule as  `timer.schedule(doAsynchronousTask, 15000,15000 );` and
maintain a counter for counting if it reached 15 times